# get All distinct (by ID) Users list and count only thoose who is Active

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get All distinct User list and count only thoose who is Active
and get something like

```
ID | Count | Active
1  |  0    | False
2  |  1    | True
3  |  6    | True
```

but when i do

```
SELECT ID,COUNT(*)
FROM Users 
WHERE Active='True'
GROUP BY ID
```

I got All Distinct Which Active

```
ID | Count | Active
2  |  1    | True
3  |  6    | True
```

How to write query to get what i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the condition into the aggregate:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(CASE WHEN Active='True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Users 
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to remove the `where` clause.  If `active` only takes on the values `True` and `False` (and NULL), then this will work:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) as cnt, MAX(Active)
FROM Users 
GROUP BY ID;
```

If `Active` can take on other values, then you might want:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) as cnt,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Active = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as Active
FROM Users 
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin . . . The question was originally tagged mysql, so I had used  MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) as count,
       (CASE WHEN count > 0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as Active
FROM test 
GROUP BY ID,count
```

The output will come as below:

```
ID  count   Active
1   1   False
2   1   True
3   1   True
```